# Директория для input type=file

Tags: javascript, файлы, input, файловая-система, activex

Есть следующая задача - отправить определенные файлы на сервер без участия пользователя (или с минимальным участием). Есть форма с `input type=file`. Насколько я знаю, нельзя из **JS**-кода выбрать файл?

Можно ли каким-либо образом задать директорию, которая будет открываться при активации input? Можно ли как-то выкрутиться с помощью **ActiveX**?

Comment: Силами `input`-а нельзя. Это сделано осознанно, чтобы всякие скрипты не шастали по диску пользователя.

Comment: ок, задать начальную директорию для диалога выбора файлов тоже нельзя?

Comment: Сходу наткнулся на [это](https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/automatically-put-a-default-filename-in-input-type-file-value.2192852/). Но, что есть операционная система - не Windows?